# searching and replace without consuming what you are searching for

Tags: regex, vim

Say I have lines like this:

```
'alpha' 123 
'beta' 678
'alpha' 998
'gamma' 212
```

And using the search & replace regex in VIM, turn it into this:

```
'alpha' 123 : alpha
'beta' 678 : beta
'alpha' 998 : alpha
'gamma' 212 : gamma
```

Basically, the search won't be replacing what it's searching for, but instead just using it for something else. In my head, this should work:

```
:g/'\(.*\)'/s/$/: \1/g
```

But that didn't do it. How do I not consume what I'm searching for but retain it for use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  do it directly  in the substitute command,  using the `\zs`  which is
really  useful for  building  things  like zero  width  matches (that  doesn't
"consume").

```
:%s/'\(.*\)'.*\zs/ : \1
```

The `\zs`  marks the  beginning of  the match. It's  like "starting  the match
here". So, first  the content of the parenthesis are  captured, then the extra
`.*` matches everything  up to the end  of the line, and the  `\zs` now resets
the match  to that point,  meaning not at  all is part  of the match,  but the
content of the parens were captured.

The substitution part substitutes the end of  the line location with `:` and
the matched group.

[`:h \zs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Czs)

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The initial `g` for the match does not capture for replacement; it is only used for grouping for the search.  Instead use this, which is a little simpler too:

```
%s/'\(.*\)'.*/& : \1/
```

The `&` replaces everything that was matched.

Comment: I'm using a variation of the example sidyll gave but this is good as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

This command should work:

```
:%s/\v'(\w*)'.*/\0 : \1
```

(well, it did here with your sample text)

Answer (score 0):

macro works for your example too: (didn't test in vim, but should work.)

cursor at the beginning of the 1st line:

```
qqyi'A : <esc>pjq
```

then `x@q` (x is how many times you want to do )